# Switching between axes when scattering in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, plot, axes

**MATLAB**

I want to scatter on two separate axes within a for loop when creating a video.

I want to do something like the following (currently incorrect code):

```
x = rand(1,100);
y = rand(1,100)*2;
z = rand(1,100)*3;

figure('units','normalized','position',[.01 .3 .7 1]);

ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);

for loop_n = 1:numel(x)
   hold on
   scatter(ax1,x,y) % can't do this, but how?
   scatter3(ax2,x,y,z) % can't do this, but how?
end
```

In this code, the 'scatter' and 'scatter3' cannot use an axis handle as input.

What is the correct way to do this? I realise I can do this individually (i.e. a loop for each axis). However, I want to create a movie that does both at the same time.

Comment: You haven't explained what about the code you've shown is incorrect.  What exactly is it that you want to do?  Do you want to plot only one set of points in each loop?  Or keep the old points and add a new point?  Something else?

Comment: I had the text within the code, but I have added more details now. Thanks for highlighting this.

Comment: What do you mean `cannot use an axis handle as input`?  The code you give executes as expected.  What are you seeing that you don't expect?

Comment: At least in the latest and greatest you can do `scatter(ax,...)`, according to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html). I don’t know if this is new syntax and/or when it was introduced, but it currently works.